# Select longest duration time (data type field) and client name SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Client 
(
    client_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Projects 
(
    project_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    project_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date DATE NOT NULL,
    client_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT client_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES Client(client_id)
);
 
INSERT INTO Client (client_id, name, address) 
VALUES (1, 'Joe Doe', '11 Henry Smith St.Chelsea, MA 02150');
         
INSERT INTO Client (client_id, name, address) 
VALUES (2, 'James Doe', '74 East Sierra Ave. Batavia, OH 45103');
         
INSERT INTO Projects (project_id, project_name, start_date, end_date, client_id) 
VALUES (1, 'YYY', TO_DATE('2020/12/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
        TO_DATE('2020/12/30 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1);

INSERT INTO Projects (project_id, project_name, start_date, end_date, client_id) 
VALUES (2, 'XXX', TO_DATE('2020/11/01 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
        TO_DATE('2020/12/30 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 2);
```

I want to select project with maximum duration time together with employee name.

I wrote this SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    p.project_name, c.name, 
FROM
    Projects p, Client c
WHERE
    p.client_id = c.client_id 
    AND max_time = (SELECT MAX(p.end_date - p.start_date) FROM Projects p);
```

But I get an error

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Here's the code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00720/1

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have glitches in column names in the fiddle, and an unwanted trailing comma after `c.name`.

Consider:

```
SELECT p.project_name, c.name
FROM Projects p
INNER JOIN Client c ON p.client_id = c.client_id 
WHERE (p.end_date - p.start_date)  = (
      SELECT MAX(end_date - start_date) FROM Projects
);
```

In Oracle 12 or higher you can also use a `FETCH` clause, as suggested by Gordon Linoff. I would recommend `WITH TIES` to make the query equivalent to your original code:

```
SELECT p.project_name, c.name
FROM Projects p
INNER JOIN Client c ON p.client_id = c.client_id 
ORDER BY p.end_date - p.start_date DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

In older versions, you can use `RANK()` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT p.project_name, c.name,
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY p.end_date - p.start_date DESC) as rn
    FROM Projects p
    INNER JOIN Client c ON p.client_id = c.client_id 
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just using `fetch first`?

```
SELECT p.project_name, c.name
FROM Projects p JOIN
     Client c
     ON p.client_id = c.client_id 
ORDER BY (p.estimated_end_date - p.project_start_date) 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8cadbb323af4fc9b909f47b3c9ffdd35) is a db<>fiddle.  The Oracle version on SQLFiddle is quite out-of-date and doesn't support `FETCH FIRST`.

Comment: OK, thank you, but still the same error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00720/5

Comment: @mazix . . . I included a db<>fiddle because that version is quite out-of-date.